# Duplicated identifiers error after typescript and node update

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor

I get the following error (and many others similar to this) when i try to build:

typings/selenium-webdriver/selenium-webdriver.d.ts(12,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Driver'.

This error started appearing after i updated to typescript v2.
I have reference to the tds.d.ts in my index.ts

any idea how to fix this errors?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the selenium-webdriver *.ts files are being included more than once.  Check out this link (documentation snippet below):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

> @types, typeRoots and types
>
> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.

In your console output, if you scroll down and look for any repeat in your "Duplicate identifier 'Driver'" error message, you will likely see something like:

> node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts(12,11): error
>   TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Driver'.

In your tsconfig.json file, you can play around with the setting "typeRoots", which is an array of explicit "type" root directories/locations to be considered during compilation.  My guess is you would want yours to look like one of the following to prevent the automatic loading of multiple similar "typeRoots":

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./typings"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

There are also some other tsconfig.json attributes that may be of interest to you, such as "files", "exclude", "include", and "types".